# Ui using jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

i am trying to learn jetpack compose. please suggest me correct way to achieve below UI. As you can see there are three item on screen. i want to align 1 item to centre of screen and other two below 1 item.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You should check ConstraintLayout for Compose to achieve this, since it uses MultiMeasureLayout i never use it. If it allows you to center an item inside a parent you can link your other two items under it

Second option is to use `Modififier.onSizeChanged` and `Modifier.offset`. Find dimensions of your big item and set offset as half of the difference between parent and this item while your first item and others are inside a Column.

Third option is two write your own `Layout`. You need to center your item manually by finding half of the difference between parent and the item and then place other items below each other but since you are new this might be complicated for you.